# Nested path contains a colon

Tags: i18next

My JSON file is this:

```
{
   "errors": {
     "missing_permissions:can_trade": "lorem ipsum"
   }
}
```

I then try to access this translation with the following but none work:

```
t(`errors.missing_permissions:can_trade`)
t(`errors['missing_permissions:can_trade']`)
```

Anyway to access this?

Comment: Do you need to wrap your variable w/in the template literal?  I.e., within your parentheses, like this: `${errors["missing_permissions:can_trade"]}`? Also, you're using the word "error" rather than "errors".

Comment: Thanks Marc I tried both, thney dont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I18next has a special meaning for `colon` - indicates a namespace.

you can tell it to ignore the colon in the key by passing `{ nsSeparator: false }`.

```js
t('errors.missing_permissions:can_trade', {nsSeparator: false});
```